# setup remote sql server

Tags: mysql, remote-access, host

I've got a small database which is going to be used 1mo/year. I also need a remote access to this database. I have tried dozens of free mysql database servers, but they're all too slow. I mean queries are being executed for ages. For example, it takes 2 mins to execute 10 queries from my Application. What I want is to setup a remote access to my localhost database. I've granted access for '%' IPs, commented bind-address in MySQL config file, but it seems to be working only for local network. 
**The question is:** how do I put my SQL server into the web so anyone could access it using my IP as a host from any location in the world? Is it even possible? At least give me directions how to find an answer. Ty. P.S.: IP is static

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are not synonyms. They are two vastly different DBMSs, one from Oracle and the other from MS. Please use only tags that are actually relevant to your question, instead of just randomly adding those that sound familiar. Tags have meaning and purpose here. Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite sorry for confusing. its mysql